# How to share a (spring) singleton service with Spark?

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark

I have a small Spark "launcher" able to instanciate a service via Spring xml application context and then "broadcasts" it in order to make it available on remote nodes.

I suppose when a Spring service is instanciated, all dependencies are instanciated and injected at the same time, so broadcasting it should broadcast everything on remote nodes. My DAOs are not accessing a remote database, instead they use inner collections which are loaded at startup from xml files (in dao constructors).

This works fine when I launch my app via spark-submit and "local" mode, but when I use "yarn-cluster" mode, I receive an exception saying my inner collections inside DAOs are empty.

Could someone tell me what is happening here ? Is there a maximum depth for broadcasting ?

All my objects are Serializable and my inner collections are mostly maps (HashMap). I've tried to declare collections as "static" but it has no effect on the broadcasting...

Some lines of code if it makes it more clear :

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
MyService myService = (MyService) applicationContext.getBean("myService");

Broadcast<MyService> broadcastedService = sparkContext.broadcast(myService);
```

And in closure :

```
((MyService) broadcastedService.value()).myAction(rddItemFromRddCollection);
```

The problem is some of inner final serializable objects inside "myService" are not serialized on nodes. I don't get any warning or error before the app detects required data are missing. It looks like myService is recreated without inner data. Maybe I'm just basic how serialization works, does it call "new" for myService on each node, then tries to populate with main reference service ? Or some fields are just assumed as "transient" for some reason and ignored silently ?

My inner collection inside service is declared like this :

```
private Map myMap<S, I> = new HashMap<S, I>();
```

Should I avoid inline initialization when dealing with serialization ?

Comment: Which serilization settings are you using? Also can you print out the object thats being received on the other side?

Comment: Could you use something like mapPartitions and spin up the singleton on each node?

Comment: 1. I'm using sparkContext.broadcast(myService) https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables. 2. I don't have any problem with input RDD, I have problem with collections owned by DAOs serialized via broadcast.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459343/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-serialization-and-java-serialization for a more detailed question and the answer.