# What is the difference between Spark Serialization and Java Serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I'm using Spark + Yarn and I have a service that I want to call on distributed nodes.

When I serialize this service object "by hand" in a Junit test using java serialization, all inner collections of the service are well serialized and deserialized :

```
  @Test
  public void testSerialization() {  

    try (
        ConfigurableApplicationContext contextBusiness = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("myService.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        ) {

      final MyService service = (MyService) contextBusiness.getBean("myServiceImpl");

      objectOutputStream.writeObject(service);
      objectOutputStream.flush();

    } catch (final java.io.IOException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testDeSerialization() throws ClassNotFoundException {  

    try (
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("myService.ser");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        ) {

      final MyService myService = (MyService) objectInputStream.readObject();

      // HERE a functionnal test who proves the service has been fully serialized and deserialized      .

    } catch (final java.io.IOException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

But when I try to call this service via my Spark launcher, wether I broadcast the service object or not, some inner collection (a HashMap) disappears (is not serialized) like if it was tagged as "transient" (but it's not transient neither static) :

```
JavaRDD<InputOjbect> listeInputsRDD = sprkCtx.parallelize(listeInputs, 10);
JavaRDD<OutputObject> listeOutputsRDD = listeInputsRDD.map(new   Function<InputOjbect, OutputObject>() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public OutputObject call(InputOjbect input) throws TarificationXmlException { // Exception

    MyOutput output = service.evaluate(input);
    return (new OutputObject(output));
  }
});
```

same result if I broadcast the service :

```
final Broadcast<MyService> broadcastedService = sprkCtx.broadcast(service);      
JavaRDD<InputOjbect> listeInputsRDD = sprkCtx.parallelize(listeInputs, 10);
JavaRDD<OutputObject> listeOutputsRDD = listeInputsRDD.map(new   Function<InputOjbect, OutputObject>() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public OutputObject call(InputOjbect input) throws TarificationXmlException { // Exception

    MyOutput output = broadcastedService.getValue().evaluate(input);
    return (new OutputObject(output));
  }
});
```

If I launch this same Spark code in local mode instead of yarn cluster mode, it works perfectly.

So my question is : What is the difference between Spark Serialization and Java Serialization ? (I'm not using Kryo or any customized serialization).

EDIT : when I try with Kryo serializer (without registering explicitly any class), I have the same problem.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Spark serialization". You haven't shown the key detail, which is this HashMap field. I assume it's a static member somewhere and not actually serialized at all.

Comment: Sorry but how could it be serialized in first example if it was not serializable at all ?

Comment: How could what be serialized? That's the key question

Comment: Man sorry, but I don't get your point. It's a HashMap<Key, Value> with value being a Hierarchy of serializable value (I can't show it more it's a complex object). The proof it is serializable is in first example, do u understand this example or do u need precisions ? My point is Spark does some additionnal filtering on serialization and not only objectOutputStream/objectIutputStream serialization

Comment: There is no HashMap in this code

Comment: There are detailed explanation on why, if u just care to read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found it out thanks to one of our experimented data analyst.

So, what was this mystery about ?

- It was NOT about serialization (java or Kryo)
- It was NOT about some pre-treatment or post-treatment Spark would do before/after serialization
- It was NOT about the HashMap field which is fully serializable (this one is obvious if u read the first example I give, but not for everyone  ;)

So...

The whole problem was about this :

> "if I launch this same Spark code in local mode instead of yarn cluster
>   mode, it works perfectly."

In "yarn cluster" mode the collection was unable to be initialized, cause it was launched on a random node and couldn't access to, the initial reference datas on disk. In local mode, there was a clear exception when the initial datas where not found on disk, but in cluster mode it was fully silent and it looked like the problem was about serialization.

Using "yarn client" mode solved this for us.